# How to get correct data in a large xml file?

Tags: c++, xml, xpath, large-data

I have a *large xml file* (contains about *few million records*) and need to get about *100 records* (based on `id` or something like that)

I tried **TinyXml** and **Xalan-C** but both of them using `DOM`, therefore it cause a `out of memory` issue.

Is there a C/C++ library that can do that without loading all data to memory as `DOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) parser like [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)

Answer (score 2):

How about Apache Xerces?
It's pretty damn mature and is optimized for performance (i.e. it won't read your complete files into memory!).

Answer (score 0):

The Saxon-EE XSLT processor can handle a subset of XSLT in streaming mode (that is, without building a tree in memory). For details see

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming.xml

It's not C/C++, but you don't say whether that's a hard constraint.